# How to pass a function with parameters as an argument to a function?

Tags: c#

I wish to create an extension method that takes A function with a parameter of `IEnumerable<T>`.

```
int NumberOfRetries = 3;
string TableName = "Table";

Method(EnumerableParameter).RetrySection(EnumerableParameter,TableName ,NumberOfRetries);
```

### Function to be extended

```
bool Method(IEnumerable<int> param)
{
  foreach(var item in param)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(item);
  }
  return true;
}
```

I am having difficulty making the code compile

```
RetrySection(() => Method(EnumerableParameter),EnumerableParameter,TableName ,NumberOfRetries);
```

for both options.

```
Method(EnumerableParameter).RetrySection(EnumerableParameter,TableName,NumberOfRetries);
```

### Extension Method

```
public static void RetrySection(this Func<IEnumerable<T>,bool> action, IEnumerable<T> parameter,string databaseTable,int jobcount)
        {
            int jobRowCount = ValidateTable(databaseTable).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            int retry = 0;

            do
            {
                action(parameter);

                jobRowCount = ValidateTable(databaseTable).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                retry++;
            }
            while ((jobRowCount < (jobcount * 2)) && retry < 3);
        }
```

I'm getting the error `Func<IEnumerable<int>,bool>` does not take 0 arguments.

Comment: Try adding braces to the first one, like `() => { return Method(EnumerableParameter); }`

Comment: You have to use a valid _delegate_ instance when calling that extension method. You can't extend the original method call itself. You need to pass a delegate created from the method, which precludes use of the method-group-to-delegate inference feature of the language. You could do `((Func<IEnumerable<T>, bool>)Method).RetrySection(EnumerableParameter, ...)` or `RetrySection(Method, EnumerableParameter, ...)`. Though frankly, I find either missing the point of a generalized retry implementation. See duplicate for how you _ought_ to be doing this.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use:

```
Method.RetrySection(EnumerableParameter,TableName ,NumberOfRetries);
```

because that is what RetrySection is defined to work on - Func<IEnumerable,bool>, instead of the result - bool.

Or, in case of the second example:

```
RetrySection(Method,EnumerableParameter,TableName ,NumberOfRetries);
```

Comment: how does action get invoked. in the do while loop if i'm extending a boolean?

Comment: You are not extending a booelan, you are extending a function that takes an  IEnumerable<T> and returns a boolean: `void RetrySection(this Func<IEnumerable<T>,bool> action`

Comment: I don't think the first option compiles as `Method.RetrySection`. You should have to cast the method as `((Func<IEnumerable<int>, bool>)Method).RetrySection`

Comment: You are right @devNull, it is required: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/TqyVJX